# How to make slide in latex

Tags: beamer, itemize, framed

I want to create a presentation about English Tense in latex. Till now I create three slide. 1st slide is a title slide. 2nd slide is for Content slide,3rd is a outline slide of my full presentation.

Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Montpellier}

\title{Tense at a Glance}
\date{December 2018}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Content}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Section 1:Outline of the document}[***Problem: When I click here I want to go to Outline of the document slide only.How to navigate to a particular slide*** ]
\section{Section 2:Present Simple vs Present Continuous}
\section{Section 3: Present Continuous vs Present Perfect Continuous }
\begin{frame}{Outline of the document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Present Simple vs Present Continuous[***Problem: I want to create a navigation here also. So when the user click on it, it navigate to Present Simple vs Present Continuous slide***]
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Present Simple vs Present Continuous}[***Want to add two sentence under the present simple vs present continuous***]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I added here a picture to show what I want exactly
[image: Picture description of above code]

I am trying to see what I actually want in this picture. In the picture the sentence with ***blue color represent link***. in slide 3 as per picture when user click on ***Present Simple vs Present continuous*** it navigate to slide 4 which describe broadly present simple vs present continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table of contents will automatically link to the correct slides if don't place all your `\section`s at the start of the document, but at the place where each of the sections starts in your code

If you still need to manually insert links, you can label your frames and use `\hyperlink{<labelname>}{Text}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{Montpellier}

\title{Tense at a Glance}
\date{December 2018}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Content}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Section 1: Outline of the document}
\begin{frame}{Outline of the document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \hyperlink{foo}{Present Simple vs Present Continuous}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2: Present Simple vs Present Continuous}
\begin{frame}[label=foo]{Present Simple vs Present Continuous}


\end{frame}

\section{Section 3: Present Continuous vs Present Perfect Continuous }
\begin{frame}[label=bar]{Present Continuous vs Present Perfect Continuous}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```